# attempting to send cookies via curl php

Tags: php, cookies, curl

When attempting to send the cookies file contents to a url, it apparently isn't being send correctly. What am I missing and doing wrong?

Here's the present code. I've checked it in developer tools and the cookies are not being sent via the REQUEST COOKIES. And I know it's not working properly because the page should render differently than it does.

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/products/red-box-diamonds/?noAjax=True&currentPage=1';

// open a site with cookies
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
#curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'new3.txt');   // Send Cookies.
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $file);   // Receive Cookies.
$content2 = curl_exec($ch2);

curl_close( $ch2 );
```

*EDIT*:
I've also tried to use:

```
dirname(__FILE__) . '/new2.txt';
```

But that didn't work either.

Comment: what is the output you are getting on var_dump($content2);

Comment: I get a page - but I know it's not the right page. Basically if no cookie is set -there's a ton of options/links. If there is a cookie set, there's only one option/link. Right now - it returns the ton, not the one

Comment: what is the method the url is expecting. is it a post/get method?

Comment: If your page is expecting page redirection change to curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); if you don't have thecookie file "new3.txt", please create it. Also use curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'new3.txt');

Answer (score 0):

Is it this page you're trying to access? http://www.stuller.com/products/red-box-diamonds/

I cannot see any cookies when submitting the page or when options are changed. The parameters all appear to be GET, not cookie nor POST.